# Can I use two developer account to publish app in on iMac?

Tags: xcode, macos

I need to publish apple app with two diff developer account in one mac, but I don't know how to do that.

I check the internet, some one said, I should create two diff iOS user for the two developer account, I'm trying this, but I don't know how to share the xCode between the two account, is this possible? or I need to install that for each account?

Could some one tell me what should I do?

Comment: What's the context that means you need to publish the same app from two different developer accounts?

Comment: I mean publish different app from each account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I mean publish different app from each account."

In that case just make two user accounts on the iMac and launch Xcode from the relevant account.

Be aware that in order for both users to publish apps you'll need separate developer accounts with Apple (unless both users are part of a company account).

Comment: How to launch xCode from the relevant account?

Comment: As long as it is installed, just go to `Applications > Xcode` from the relevant user account and double click.